# Store data in discord message for button component

Tags: discord, discord.js, embed

I want to make a simple bot that does some things when someone clicks a list item.

To make this possible I need to store the list item's id in the message. I didn't see any ways to store data in a message without showing it, so I added it to the footer and when the button triggers it gets the first embed's footer in the interaction's message.

My problem with this solution is that it looks bad.

Collectors are not an option because these list items are sent to a channel once when the channel is created, and if the bot restarts the collectors won't trigger.

How would you guys solve this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Surely there's a better way of doing this. How will the ids come into play?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved this. I don't know how I've never thought of this before.

Basically I created a table in my database that has 2 columns:

- discord message id
- data

When I send the message to the channel I just store the data with the message's id. When the user clicks the button I just retrieve the data by the message id.